# eslinting issue and my typescript react app is bonking out

Tags: typescript, webstorm, eslint

I think this app is getting the best of me. I am using typescript, sass(scss) and the typescript is on a per file basis. My simple setup is generating errors, yet, its regular react/js.. standard stuff. Anyone have any ideas. Below is my eslint file and a screenshot of the very simple component and the errors....

I believe the issue is that my linting is not working for ".js" files. My app needs to have both, .tsx and .js, as typescript is not required. Can use it or not.
[image]

.eslint file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin", 'react', 'prettier', 'import'],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "eslint-config-prettier",
    "eslint-config-prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "airbnb-base",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
  ],
  "globals": {},
  "rules": {
    "strict": ["error", "never"],
    "import/prefer-default-export": 1,
    "global-require": 1,
    "react/jsx-key": 1,
    "prefer-destructuring": 1
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true,
    "es2020": true
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'babel-module': {
        "import/resolver": {
          src: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
        },
      },
    },
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.tsx?"],
      "excludedFiles": "**/*.js",
      "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      files: ['**/__tests__/**'],
      settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
          jest: {
            jestConfigFile: path.join(__dirname, '/jest.config.js'),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Also, I've always done my development in webstorm and here is my javascript setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the file as `jsx`/`tsx` when opening the file. Or configure it manually:

`Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript.`

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/

Comment: I believe its set correctly. I added the screen shot of the my setting in webstorm.

Comment: Could you try creating a new file, `test.js` and insert the same content there?